# Azure Autoscaling (400) Bad Request

Tags: azure, autoscaling

I try to increase my instance count by code behind.

First of all I created one .cer file and .pfx file and I upload it into .pfx to cloudservice certificates and .cer to settings --> management certificates.

After I used .cer file in my code. I don't know very well this uplod file is it true ?

Here is my code :

```
string subscriptionId = "c034e905-......";
        string serviceName = "multitenant";
        string configFileName = "ServiceConfiguration.cscfg";
        string roleName = "Multi.Web";

        XNamespace xs = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration";
        XDocument configDocument = XDocument.Parse(String.Join("", File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetFullPath(configFileName))));
        XAttribute instanceCountAttribute = configDocument.Element(xs + "ServiceConfiguration")
                                                            .Elements(xs + "Role")
                                                            .Where(xRole => xRole.Attribute("name").Value == roleName).SingleOrDefault()
                                                            .Element(xs + "Instances")
                                                            .Attribute("count");

        int currentInstanceCount = int.Parse(instanceCountAttribute.Value);
```

and I am checking some fields in my VM and I incease my currentInstanceCount .

```
double processorTotal = Convert.ToDouble(performanceCounter.CounterValue);

            instanceCountAttribute.Value = (currentInstanceCount + 1).ToString();

            var serviceManagment = ServiceManagementHelper.CreateServiceManagementChannel("WindowsAzureEndPoint",
                new X509Certificate2("multitenant.cer"));
            var changeConfigInput = new ChangeConfigurationInput();
            changeConfigInput.Configuration = ServiceManagementHelper.EncodeToBase64String(configDocument.ToString());
            try
            {
                serviceManagment.ChangeConfigurationBySlot(subscriptionId, serviceName, "Production", changeConfigInput);
            }
            catch (WebException e) 
            { 
                throw new Exception(new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()); 
            }
```

ChangeConfigurationBySlot method is throwing exception :

**The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.**

Where am I wrong ? I couldn't understand. Is it about method parameters or wrong upload certificate ?

Do you have any estimate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

It is not about certification.First I get the production configuration file and I change it's current instance count and redeploy.

Here is the code :

var deployment = managementClient.GetDeploymentBySlot(subscriptionId, serviceName, "Production");

```
        string configurationXml = ServiceManagementHelper.DecodeFromBase64String(deployment.Configuration);
        serviceConfiguration = XDocument.Parse(configurationXml);

        XNamespace xs = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration";
        instanceCountAttribute = serviceConfiguration.Element(xs + "ServiceConfiguration")
                                                            .Elements(xs + "Role")
                                                            .Where(xRole => xRole.Attribute("name").Value == roleName).SingleOrDefault()
                                                            .Element(xs + "Instances")
                                                            .Attribute("count");
        currentInstanceCount = int.Parse(instanceCountAttribute.Value);
```